# Next Image: hostname "..." is not configured under images in your `next.config.js` ... but it is

Tags: next.js

I'm getting the following error when I start my (recently updated to the latest Next.js) dev site:

> Error: Invalid src prop
> (http://dev.mysite.com:3001/images/group/someImage.jpg) on
> `next/image`, hostname "dev.mysite.com" is not configured under images
> in your `next.config.js` See more info:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

If you follow that link, it will explain that you need to add the hostname to the Next config ... but mine does have the appropriate config:

```
images: {
  remotePatterns: [
    {
      protocol: 'https',
      hostname: 'dev.mysite.com',
      pathname: '/images/**',
      port: '3001',
    }
}
```

I also tried setting the (old) `domains` property instead, but that didn't help.  Does anyone have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the protocol in the config file does not match the protocol in the error message.

Comment: Duh, I completely missed the `s`; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stucking with this problem,
you **can't let any of these values** `undefined`
, Typescript will not allow it to work.

In my case, I was not adding anything to the *pathname*.

So, don't forget to fill all these values.
I add ** (I guess it's a wildcard character, not sure if it's actually that)
and it did the trick!

```
pathname: '**',
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, the width & height parameters in Image component are causing invalid request. Try wild card for pathname='**' in next.config.js